# Using Parse.com in Android Intent Service

Tags: android, parse-platform, intentservice, android-intentservice

I want to upload some data to my database on Parse.com from a background service on Android. I have used Parse in Activities before and used to write the following lines in its onCreate() method:

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "kw0FN094jFEtdCMrYXNgSYo3wqKhXAEm2RBcLDEq", "AKLRbWFt0ZhWqw1huWA0avuk9iQB7Z1qKVHXSslj");
```

When I try to add the same to my service and then call the service from my android app,  the logcat shows this error:

```
07-07 19:43:27.393    1053-1578/com.example.shikhar.trackmydevice E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[UploadService]
Process: com.example.shikhar.trackmydevice, PID: 1053
java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
        at com.parse.Parse.enableLocalDatastore(Parse.java:65)
        at com.example.shikhar.trackmydevice.UploadService.onHandleIntent(UploadService.java:81)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I have also declared my service in the AndroidManifest.xml Here's a snippet:

```
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.shikhar.appname.UploadService"/>

</application>
```

This is the code of my Upload Service:

```
package com.example.shikhar.appname;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;


public class UploadService extends IntentService {

protected static final String TAG = "UploadService: ";



public UploadService() {
    super("UploadService");
}

/**
 * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
 * the intent that started the service. When this method returns, IntentService
 * stops the service, as appropriate.
 */

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "kw0FN094jFEtdCMrYXNgSYo3wqKhXAEm2RBcLDEq", "AKLRbWFt0ZhWqw1huWA0avuk9iQB7Z1qKVHXSslj");



}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    }
}
```

I'm starting and stopping the service from a single ImageButton in main Activity. This is the code in onCreate() of my Activity:

```
btnService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity, UploadService.class);

            if(serviceIsRunning(UploadService.class))
            {
                stopService(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                startService(intent);
            }

            if(serviceIsRunning(UploadService.class))
            {
                btnService.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_service_stop);
            }
            else
            {
                btnService.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_service_start);

            }


        }
    });
```

The above code uses the following method defined outside the onCreate inside the class of myActivity:

```
 protected boolean serviceIsRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Please suggest me. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try initialazing parse in your custom Application, so you don't have to initialize it in every activity or service:

```
public class MyAplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "XXXX", "XXXX");
    }
}
```

Then in your AndroidManifest.xml you add the name:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyAplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```